# Interpolation: Issue in recognizing non null columns of pandas dataframe by scipy functions

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, interpolation

I wrote a function for interpolating missing values of a pandas dataframe using the following interpolation techniques: Linear, Polynomial, Cubic Spline, & Radial Basis.

In case a column given as input doesn't contain null values, an error message is returned, "No null values in column xyz". I executed this code last week & for columns with no null values it gave the above mentioned error message.

But today when I'm executing the same code again I'm getting different error messages for different interpolation techniques:

Error messages for columns with no null values (I'm running my code on Postman):

1. Radial Basis: "zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity"
2. Cubic Spline: "`x` must contain at least 2 elements".
3. Linear & Polynomial: ValueError: Out of range float values are not JSON compliant.

In my code, I am dealing with handling infinite values & cleaning the columns of special characters & whitespaces. That fixed the value error, but today again I'm getting the same error for the same dataset that I tested last week.

I used Scipy library for the code. I tried upgrading & downgrading scipy to diffeent versions but the issue still persists.

A week ago my code was working fine, but today when I run the same unchanged code again it's giving me multiple different errors for different techniques.

May I know why this happens & how I can fix these issues?

Comment: `Internal Server Error` That sounds like an HTTP error, not a Scipy error. Are you hosting this function on a website somewhere?

Comment: Not hosting on a website, but wrote an API & checking the output on Postman.

Comment: Is your API translating some other error into "Internal Server Error?"

Comment: Yes, actually. The error is: ValueError: Out of range float values are not JSON compliant. I did write the code to deal with infinite values & clean the columns of special characters & whitespaces. That fixed the value error, but today again I'm getting the same error for the same dataset that I tested last week.